# How to rename values from list based on information provided in the list name

Tags: r, substitution

I have 4 values in the list

```
c("JSMITH_WWWFRecvd2001_asof_20220901.xlsx", "WSMITH_AMEXRecvd2002_asof_20220901.xlsx",
"PSMITH_WWWFRecvd2003_asof_20220901.xlsx", "QSMITH_AMEXRecvd2004_asof_20220901.xlsx")
```

I would like my outcome to be

```
"wwwf_01","amex_02","wwwf_03","amex_04"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub`:

```r
tolower(sub('.+_(.+)Recvd[0-9][0-9](..).+', '\\1_\\2', x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work. You can extract the string you want with `str_extract()` make it lower case with `tolower()` and paste the formatted counter to the end of the string with a "_" separator =.

```
paste(tolower(stringr::str_extract(x,"WWWF|AMEX" )), sprintf("%02d",seq_along(x)), sep = "_")
```